# How to disable semantic highlighting for certain filetypes only?

Tags: neovim, syntax-highlighting, lua, lsp

Using Neovim's native LSP interface, I noticed that semantic highlighting provided by LSP makes things worse for certain languages, so I want to disable it based on filetype.

I know about possibility of setting `client.server_capabilities.semanticTokensProvider = nil` using `on_attach` callback, but disabling semantics token provider entirely seems to have other negative side-effects. So instead I'm trying to do it using suggestions from `:help lsp-semantic-highlight`:

```
You can disable semantic highlights by clearing the highlight groups:

    -- Hide semantic highlights for functions
    vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, '@lsp.type.function', {})

    -- Hide all semantic highlights
    for _, group in ipairs(vim.fn.getcompletion("@lsp", "highlight")) do
      vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, group, {})
    end

You probably want these inside a |ColorScheme| autocommand.
```

Running the loop from example works perfectly on disabling it globally, but I'm confused on how to do that for certain filetypes only, without affecting open files of other types.

Comment: Unfortunately, highlight groups are global AFAIK.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble `nvim_set_hl` takes namespace as a first argument, I was hoping maybe that can help. But I myself am clueless on how highlight namespaces work.

Comment: Have a check for this: https://gist.github.com/swarn/fb37d9eefe1bc616c2a7e476c0bc0316, should work when specifying `<type>` and `<ft>`

Answer (score 0):

You should disable semantic highlighting for **specific LSP** (for the filetype) that you want to disable.

`on_init` is a great For example, if you want disable semantic highlighting from `lua_ls` (Lua):

```lua
lspconfig.lua_ls.setup {
  ---@param client lsp.Client
  on_init = function(client, _)
    client.server_capabilities.semanticTokensProvider = nil  -- turn off semantic tokens
  end,
  on_attach = ...,
  settings = ...,
}
```

For more details, read `:help vim.lsp.start_client()`